Failed to load Info.plist - Xcode and simulator issues when running app on iOS simulator
I get this error when running my app from Xcode to an iOS simulator iPhone 15 Pro Max:

App installation failed: Unable to Install “Fevent”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about "/Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-04-03 20:46:41 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
}
--
App installation failed: Unable to Install “Fevent”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about "/Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
}
--
Unable to Install “Fevent”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about "/Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
--
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework; Extra info about "/Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/j.taoufik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B0903BDD-D9AB-44AE-876D-9C7BA157EE67/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.iz8rlx/extracted/Fevent.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 35
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
    SourceFileLine = 64;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone16,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.4 (21E213)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.24";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.58";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 268;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IXUserPresentableErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--

System Information

macOS Version 14.4.1 (Build 23E224)
Xcode 15.3 (22618) (Build 15E204a)
Timestamp: 2024-04-03T22:46:41+02:00

I have been trying to find a solution but nothing works.
Including reset caches, reinstall Xcode, erase simulator data, etc.
I also tried deleting caches, but nothing worked.
This issues happened just after updating Xcode today. I don't understand why it is happening whereas rollback to old version doesn't resolve the issue too.

Do any sample apps from Apple install? When is the last time the Mac was powered down and got a clean OS start?

This firebase article looks worthy of a deeper dive to consider your dependencies - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5562

I didn't getit, why was it working before but now it is not.

Make sure you have the latest version of all 3rd party libraries.

"After several attempts and searches on google, I solved it simply by updating the package dependencies."
Did that for MobileAds library and it worked.
But the issue happened again.
It seems it was related to 15.3 Xcode version, I downgraded to 15.2 now everything is fine since a week!
